# Sticker Pack Error - missing app extension

Tags: ios-extensions, ios-stickers

> The messages stub app _ must have at least one app extension, but none
>   were found.

This is odd because I was running my sticker pack app yesterday with no problems. What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this happens when you run to a device that does not support the minimum OS.

For sticker packs the minimum iOS version is 10.0, which is what I've set my app's minimum to. I half hazardly selected the iPhone 5 simulator which is when I encountered this issue.

## Solution(s)

a. Select a device that supports the minimum iOS version set in your target's **General > Deployment Info** (I cose iPhone 8 simulator)

b. If your project runs and immediately closes then it's most likely that the sticker pack installed to the device but needs to now be enabled. Do this by opening iMessage then selecting the "..." at the bottom, select "Edit" in the top right corner, find your sticker pack and enable it on the right hand side.